# How can a project be downgraded from .NET 3.5 to .NET 2.0?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-2.0, downgrade

If the project is not using any features from .NET 3.5, how do you downgrade to 2.0?

Comment: Is there a good reason since 3.5 runs on the same engine as 2.0

Comment: @rerun: Absolutely - just because 2.0 is installed doesn't mean that 3.5 is.

Comment: Yeah, I jumped the gun. I thought the client would be happy to upgrade, but the admins aren't too keen on getting it installed on all the computers on the network. Meanwhile, I have done some work and don't feel like copying all that to the backup I have of the 2.0 version.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it already IS .NET 2.0. When I opened the project in VS 2008 for the first time, it told me it was going to upgrade, so I thought that meant it was upgrading it to .net 3.5, but apparently not. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply go into the project properties, and under "Application" find the "Target framework" option and set it to 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Go to project properties and select different destination framework on *Application tab*.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Explorer->Right-click on the project->Properties->Change runtime version to 2.0

Answer (score -1):

Open your `.vcproj` and then change the line to:

```
TargetFrameworkVersion="131072"
```

It should do the trick